# How to visualize the original data by the values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset that looks like

```
df <- data.frame(
  name = LETTERS[seq(from = 1, to = 10)],
  var1 = sample(1:20, 10),
  var2 = sample(5:25, 10),
  var3 = sample(10:30, 10),
  var4 = sample(15:35, 10),  
  var5 = sample(20:40, 10)
)
```

How can I present the original data filling the units by the value in ggplot?
Like what can be done by the Excel 'conditional formatting' function?

[image]

I guess geom_segment is involved here while my columns are a set of variables (they have meaningful names in the 'real' dataset) rather than numeric values so does my rownames (actually the first column). So I am totally lost how to set x, xend, y, yend, etc and make it just the way it is.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could achieve your desired result via `geom_tile` by first converting your data to long format using e.g. `tidyr::pivot_longer` like so:

```r
set.seed(123)

library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

df_long <- df |> 
  pivot_longer(-name, names_to = "var")

ggplot(df_long, aes(x = var, y = name, fill = value)) +
  geom_tile() +
  geom_text(aes(label = value)) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "#F7FCF5", high = "#005A32")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Is it possible to put the name in alphabetical order?

Comment: Your colors are much better than mine @Stefan!!. . I should borrow that low and high... :)

Comment: The names are in alphabetical, starting at the origin. If you want to flip it, you need `+ scale_y_reverse()`

Comment: Thx @langtang. IMHO choosing colors is in general not easy. So, I simply picked my greens from the brewer "Greens" palettes, i.e. `scales::brewer_pal(palette = "Greens")(8)[c(1, 8)]`. :D

Answer (score 2):

```
library(data.table)

ggplot(melt(setDT(df), id.var="name"),aes(variable, name, fill=value)) + 
  geom_bin2d() + 
  geom_text(aes(label=value)) + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "lightgreen", high = "darkgreen") + 
  scale_x_discrete(position = "top") + 
  scale_y_discrete(limits=rev) + 
  labs(x="", y="") + 
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

[image: bin2d]